# PHP Class Extends - Parent var in Child

Tags: php, class, variables, extend

This code do not run. I should echo parent var, in my child class. Please help.
Thanks!

```
class A {
    public $valtozo;
    function show ($num) {
        $this->valtozo = $num;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    function mas () {
        echo parent::$valtozo;
    }
}

$oszatly = new B();
$oszatly->show(55);
$oszatly->mas();
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: A::$valtozo
>   in C:\AppServ\www\testi.php on line 13

Thans mans!

Comment: $valtozo isn't a static property: just do `echo $this->valtozo;`

Comment: getter and setter are pretty usefull, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is not static, so you should not use the `::` syntax to access it. Instead use `$this->`. Change to:

```
function mas () {
    echo $this->valtozo;
}
```

By using `$this->`, you can access properties and methods from the parent class.